# C# to SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to use this string below in C# to speak to an Visual Studio SQL Server:

```
    Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Desktop\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Latex\Latex\Latex.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

The problem is that when I try to debug, etc., it comes up as an error. The database address is the cause, as it is within inverted commas.

How do resolve the issue?

Comment: "comes up as an error" ... my advice is give us the text of the error.

Comment: `\"` in code translates to `"` in output.

Comment: Either double up your \ in your connection string or add @ before the first double quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the string to either this:

```
"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\Latex\\Latex\\Latex.mdf"
```

...or this:

```
@"C:\Users\Desktop\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Latex\Latex\Latex.mdf"
```